# MongoDB update Nested field

Tags: mongodb, set

In MongoDB how do you use **`$set`** to update a nested value?

For example, consider a collection **people** with the following document:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5a7e395e20a31e44e0e7e284"),
  name: "a",
  address: [{ street: "123", town: "bar" }]
}
```

How do I update the `street` field embedded in the `address` document from `"123"` to `"Main Street"`?

Comment: is adress field necessarily an array?

Comment: @matthPen : Yes

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, but I found the solution :

```
db.collection.updateMany(
        { "address.street": "123" }, 
        { "$set": { "address.$[].street": "Main Street" } }
    )
```

Comment: With this query, you in fact will update : 
- the first document that have any adress.street="123"
- set the street for all adresses to "Main street" for this document.
As you test with one document, and one address in array, it seems to work, but you will get some problems further. See my response

Comment: @matthPen:  Could you share some issues you faced ? How about using updateMany() for that case, if i want to update all such documents.

Comment: take the doc i provided in my answer, and insert it twice in your test db. Running your query, you will see that the first document is updated (updateMany will update the two documents) , and all the street are now set to "Main Street". I don't think this is your expected behavior.

Comment: @matthPen : Thanks, but that is what my intention was to update all the matching query statements.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$set` along with `$` [postion operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) like this :

```
db.collection.update(
        { "address.street": "123" }, 
        { "$set": { "address.$.street": "Main Street" } }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) (positionnal update operator) to update the address that match (here street="123" and town="bar")

Using this slightly different model (just added addresses to better understand) :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7e395e20a31e44e0e7e284"), 
    "name" : "a", 
    "address" : [
        {
            "street" : "123", 
            "town" : "bar"
        }, 
        {
            "street" : "Lower Street", 
            "town" : "bar"
        }, 
        {
            "street" : "123", 
            "town" : "foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

The query to apply :

```
db['01'].update(
  {"_id" : ObjectId("5a7e395e20a31e44e0e7e284")},
  {$set:{"address.$[current].street":"Main Street"}},
  { arrayFilters: [{current:{street:"123","town":"bar"}} ]} 
)
```

Will result in :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7e395e20a31e44e0e7e284"), 
    "name" : "a", 
    "address" : [
        {
            "street" : "Main Street", 
            "town" : "bar"
        }, 
        {
            "street" : "Lower Street", 
            "town" : "bar"
        }, 
        {
            "street" : "123", 
            "town" : "foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613735/morphia-mongodb-update-in-embedded-array-document-fails