# Morphia Mongodb Update in Embedded Array document fails

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am new to Morphia and am trying to update a field in embedded document. This is the current structure

```
class A {

    List<B> BList;
}

class B {
    String field;
}
```

So My structure looks like the following in MongoDb :

```
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("5bab8be0032945f6e9f91d98"),
    "className" : "com.abc.A",
    "BList" : [ 
        {
            "B" : {
                "field" : "text"
                }
        }
}
```

Now I want to update B.field for all the matching queries.
I created the following UpdateOperations

```
 UpdateOperations updateOps = datastore.createUpdateOperations(A.class);
```

my filter query was fine say filter returning me all elements in A.

```
 updateOps.set("Blist.$[].B.field", "newtext");
```

when debugger reached this statement it shows `org.mongodb.morphia.query.ValidationException: Could not resolve path` 'BList.$[].B.field' against A`

I even added disableValidation But this doesnot run.

However if I ommit the positional operator it works fine but when on runnig datastore.update() it fails.
throwing this error.

```
 Write failed with error code 28 and error message 'Cannot create field B.
```

Can Anyone suggest how to do this updation on second level in morphia ?

Comment: what is your morphia version? I use version 1.3.2 and this works perfectly fine for me. Also, in the document you are trying to modify, is field B available?